# How do I Restart this class? or unload and load it?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a class, with a bunch of println's, and then I have a switch. the point is that the user has 3 options, 1 of them is wrong and takes him back to the start. I tried recreating the class from inside the class, but it didnt work, because when it would finish the recent class, it would go back to the previous class and finish it. Maybe the solution is simple, and I just don't know how to do it, I have been programing for 2 weeks in school... If you need an example, I can type one, but its just a switch with 3 cases inside it, where 2 of them say diferent things, but break the switch anyway, and the 3rd says something else, but restarts.
Any sugestions?

```
  Switch (choice1){
  case 1: System.out.println("Blabla"); break;
  case 2: System.out.println("Blabla"); break;
  case 3: System.out.println("Blabla"); break;
  default: System.out.println("That is not a valid number."); break;}
```

There... its just a switch...
EDIT: Just so you know, as I said, I don't really know much about programing with java yet, so I don't think I can fix this without some code help.

SOLVED! by myself. Look down

```
      Switch (choice1){
      case 1: System.out.println("Blabla"); break;
      case 2: System.out.println("Blabla"); break;
      case 3: System.out.println("Blabla"); break;
      default: System.out.println("That is not a valid number."); nameoftheclass nameoftheobject = new nameofthemethod(); break;}
      if (choice1 >2)
          {}
      else
          {rest of the code...}
```

Comment: my answer would be loops. show us the code for a better answer.

Comment: Please show us the code so we can understand what you mean exactly.

Comment: what do you mean by restart or load and unload?

Comment: maybe instantiate new objects of the classes ...

Comment: @praveen_mohan did you not read it? I need to go back to the start of the class if the user makes the wrong choice. (choice 3)

Comment: @radai I'm waiting for that better answer of yours

Comment: Your code does not "restart", your code would require you to repeat the same code again. Also in a programmatic point of view, that solution is poor in most aspects and should not be used.

Comment: I suggest you learn a bit more about Java and flow control https://thenewcircle.com/bookshelf/java_fundamentals_tutorial/flow_control.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered to myself, up there in the Question box.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create an init() method that does all of the initialization for the class.  In the constructor, call init().  Then later in the program when you need to start over, call init() again.

Comment: What is your class doing now when it is first created?  Anything that you are initializing in your constructor would get moved into the init method.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example with a **loop**:

```
boolean correct = false;
while(correct == false){
    //Your question and input reading needs to be here, inside the loop.
    Switch (choice1){
      case 1: System.out.println("Blabla"); correct = true; break;
      case 2: System.out.println("Blabla"); break;
      case 3: System.out.println("Blabla"); correct = true; break;
      default: System.out.println("That is not a valid number."); break;}
}
```

This will be repeated until a correct answer is chosen, indicated by the **correct flag** being set to **true**.

Note that this **is not the best way to solve it**, but a **very simple** and understandable way. If you plan on having **multiple questions** this code should be extracted to a **method** that accepts: question, answers, indicator of which answer is correct.

Comment: thank you, but I believe I fixed it before you posted this. Thanks for the help anyway. How do I mark my question as solved?

Comment: Your "fix" is poor, at best. You cannot mark it as solved, however you can answer your own question and accept the answer. But your "answer" is not a good one, trust the one with experience. -.-

Comment: Dude, if you are so pro, why dont you throw a perfect answer in? I don't see one by you. Also, I need to wait 8 hours to answer to myself, because I created this account ~30 minutes ago.

Comment: Simply because you would most likely not be able to comprehend that answer with regards to your current programming ability. Just a friendly pointer, acting like a child, which you probably are, you will not receive much help in the future if you continue like this.

Comment: Sir, can you please look at yourself and your previous comments? All i did was act like you but with less fancy words. Is it less childish now?

Comment: My comments were objective observations within the given context, your comment was meaningless and full of attitude that has no place on a community driven site like this.